# 404 error on service request. How to change reply status

Tags: angular, typescript, universal

I am a newbie on Angular2.
I could not find answer to my question: How to replace content of reply if a service in my module result with an error.
The scenario is that the module uses a hashed ID from the URL to perform a service request. If the URL was copied incorrectly the request fails.
We thought that at this point we should display a 404 page.
Currently, when an error is detected, I redirect to the 404 page.
It seems to me that this behavior causes problems such as that on the browser the back operation is problematic.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a page not found page

and in your routes:

```
{
    // all unvalid urls, get redirected to page not found page
    path: '**',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent,
}
```

and if you need to intercept unvalid urls in e.g your service, based on response and use:

```
this._router.navigateByUrl('/pagenotfound', { skipLocationChange: true })
```

This also uses `skipLocationChange`, so when user clicks back-button in browser, user does not get "stuck" in the 404 page, it skips that page.